# Don't show Header view after clicking next on pager

Tags: 7, views

I'm -very- close to finishing my first drupal site, I've got just one or two more hurdles to overcome and I'm hoping you can help me.

On my /news page (showing Articles), at the top I want to show the 4 most recent Articles as teasers. Below that, I want to show a grid of next 12 most recent Articles. Below that I want to include a pager to allow them to see older Articles.

Using Views and Page Manager I've created a page that gets me very close.

I have a View for "Most Recent Articles" which shows the 4 most recent teasers.

I have a View for "More Articles" which shows a grid of fields of 12 Articles with an offset of 4 so that it doesn't include the 4 most recent.

In Page Manager I created a page that includes the Most Recent Articles View and then includes the More Articles View. This works very well and gives me exactly what I want.

My Problem: When I click the "next" link in the pager at the bottom of the More Articles view, I don't want to show the Most Recent Articles anymore. I'd either like to hide that View on subsequent pages or I'd like to selective only include it on the 1st page (two different approaches to the same idea).

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an idea:

Create a third view that's a page showing articles with an offset of 16 (so it skips the 4 and the 12).  Call it 'older articles'.

Then instead of a pager, have a 'more' link under your view of 12.  It's important, in the 'Advanced' section of the view, to set the more link to go to that new views page (older articles).  The older articles page can then have its own pager!!!  But the initial articles page -- the landing page -- can just have a 'view more' link so it can hop over to the older views altogether.

Would that be sufficient?

Comment: Yea, that's exactly what I ended up doing. However, I was hoping someone had a way to do it directly instead of faking it. I'll vote this up and if no one else provides a direct solution, I'll accept this one.

Comment: Yeah, it really is a good question, and I have no other ideas.  Hopefully someone else will come up with something!